# Attachment Fu error on MAC OS X and Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, attachment-fu

Greetings.
I am encountering an issue with attachment fu and s3.

Details:
Production server - Ubuntu - imagemagick, rmagick aws-s3 gems are installed .

Error starting app:

```
vendor/plugins/attachment_fu/lib/technoweenie/attachment_fu/backends/s3_backend.rb:173:in `included': undefined method `symbolize_keys' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

See: http://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu/blob/master/lib/technoweenie/attachment_fu/backends/s3_backend.rb

Has anyone encountered this? It seems that even with the config/amazon_s3.yml, the YAML file is not read.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a wild guess here as the file you've linked to isn't the same version as the one you're using. The only mention of `symbolize_keys` in self.included is

```
@@s3_config = @@s3_config = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(@@s3_config_path)).result)[RAILS_ENV].symbolize_keys
```

Looking at that, I guess you don't have a configuration block for your current environment n config/amazon_s3.yml

Ie, if you are running in production mode, you need to have (at least)

```
production:
  bucket_name: appname
  photo_bucket_name: appname_photos
  access_key_id: <your key>
  secret_access_key: <your key>
```

in your configuration file.